# innoDB with --single-transaction or replication

Tags: mysql, database-replication, database-backups

Is it enough to add the option `--single-transaction` in mysqldump to create a backup with consistency..

Or do you need to setup master/slave replication?

`mysqldump --single-transaction -h localhost -u root ...`

The database consists of only innoDB tables

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes,

```
mysqldump --single-transaction ...
```

executes

```
SET SESSION TRANSACTION ISOLATION LEVEL REPEATABLE READ
START TRANSACTION /*!40100 WITH CONSISTENT SNAPSHOT */
UNLOCK TABLES
...
```

so this will provide you consistency. You do not need to set up replication.

For reference:

```
mysqldump ... (same as mysqldump --lock-tables ...)
```

executes:

```
LOCK TABLES `table1` READ /*!32311 LOCAL */
...
UNLOCK TABLES
...
LOCK TABLES `table2` READ /*!32311 LOCAL */
...
UNLOCK TABLES
...
```

and

```
mysqldump --lock-all-tables ...
```

executes:

```
FLUSH TABLES
FLUSH TABLES WITH READ LOCK
...
```

so for your needs, `mysqldump --single-transaction` is correct.